# How to use where to build a submatrix

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I need to make an array A from the non-zero elements of an existing array B.  In matlab I would "find" the indices of the nonzero values of B:
A=B(find(B~=0))

Could anyone suggest a way to do this in F90?  In all of my tries, I always end up with A having the same length as B

Comment: Welcome, we need to see the code you have tried to be able to say what is wrong.

Comment: As above, we'll need code to address "I always end up with A having the same length as B", but (albeit not with `where`) you can see an indication of an approach [using `pack`](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/fortran/2643/intrinsic-procedures/8789/using-pack-to-select-elements-meeting-a-condition#t=201704110901395795153).

Comment: The pack command does the job perfectly, as suggested:            Program scratch
  integer (kind = 4)   :: B(6)
  integer, allocatable :: A(:)
  B=(/1,2,0,4,0,6/)
  print *,B
  A=pack(B,B/=0)
  print *,A
End Program scratch                                                                                  I had not realized that "pack" would actually allocate the allocatable array.               Thanks for all the tips